# Show a hidden div when no results were found in a Search input

Tags: javascript, search

I'm using the [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)  **w3.js** search engine

It works fine, but I need it to display a `<div>` for when the search engine cannot match any search.

Here's my code:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="w3.filterHTML('#myTable', 'p', this.value)" placeholder="Search for names..">

<div id="myTable">
  <div>
     <p>Adele</p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <p>Agnes</p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <p>Billy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <p>Bob</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="no-data-div" style="display:none">
   <p>No Results Found :(</p>
</div>
```

and the Script:

```
<script>
var w3 = {};
w3.getElements = function (id) {
        if (typeof id == "object") {
                return [id];
        } else {
                return document.querySelectorAll(id);
        }
};
w3.filterHTML = function(id, sel, filter) {
    var a, b, c, i, ii, iii, hit;
    a = w3.getElements(id);
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         b = w3.getElements(sel);
         for (ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++) {
              hit = 0;
              if (b[ii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                hit = 1;
              }
              c = b[ii].getElementsByTagName("*");
              for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
                  if (c[iii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                       hit = 1;
                  }
              }
              if (hit == 1) {
                  b[ii].parentElement.style.display = "";                        
              } else {
                  b[ii].parentElement.style.display = "none";
              }

          }
     }
};
</script>
```

I want **"#no-data-div"** to be visible when all the others divs are hidden. How can I achieve this?

Comment: For future Googlers & readers, this question and answer shows you how to adjust the w3.js search engine script so that you can show a 'No results found.' message when no results were found in the table. This is done by altering the w3.filterHTML function declaration. We simply track the total results through the various elements (including child elements), and analyze the total results at the end (totalHits variable). If there's 0 results found, we show the no results found div/element. Hopefully this helps people in future with w3.js :) This *should* be a built in feature, but it's not :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time adjusting your code. I believe this should work for you. I commented your code so you know which each part is doing (as far as I can tell), and adjust as needed... The main addition is just the counter (totalHits++) which runs through the script so it can be analyzed at the end to decide if the no results div should be shown or not.

```
w3.filterHTML = function(id, sel, filter) {
        // w3 search filter function, adjusted by Nerdi.org (username on StackOverflow/my website)
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742504/show-a-hidden-div-when-no-results-were-found-in-a-search-input
        var a, b, c, i, ii, iii, hit;
        a = w3.getElements(id);
        // a.length will tell you # of tables (should be = to 1, as in 1 table being searched)
        var totalHits = 0; // let's get a total count. 
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
             b = w3.getElements(sel);
             // b.length will tell you # of valid selections (by tag, in this case you are searching the <p> tags)
             for (ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++) {
                  hit = 0;
                  if (b[ii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                    hit = 1;
                    totalHits++; 
                  }
                  c = b[ii].getElementsByTagName("*");
                  // c.length will tell us how many children this elem has so we can cycle through any child elements within the first selection (in this case, <p>)
                  var cLength = c.length; 
                  for (iii = 0; iii < cLength; iii++) {
                      if (c[iii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                           hit = 1;
                           totalHits++; 
                      }
                  }
                  if (hit == 1) {
                      b[ii].parentElement.style.display = "";
                  } else {
                      b[ii].parentElement.style.display = "none";
                  }
              }
         }
      // now that we've looped through all results, let's see if we found anything using our totalHits var that we set earlier :) 
      if(totalHits == 0){
        document.getElementById('no-data-div').style.display = 'block'; // show the no results found 
      } else {
        document.getElementById('no-data-div').style.display = 'none'; // hide  the no results found 
      }
    };
```